# How to install ruby(rubygems) with openssl?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When running `rvm rubygems latest` I get the error.
How fix it?

```
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/
sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/Users/sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:
/Users/sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/Users/sjc/.rvm/gem
s/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /Users/sjc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby /Users/s
jc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/setup.rb', please read /Users/sjc/.rvm/log/
ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
```

The log (rubygems.install.log) has this:

```
[2013-03-05 20:31:37] /Users/sjc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
/Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/security.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/request_set.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems.rb:195:in `finish_resolve'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/rdoc.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:440:in `uninstall_old_gemcutter'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:144:in `execute'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
    from /Users/sjc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
    from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
RubyGems 2.0.0 installed
```

Because I didn't know what I was doing, I think my earlier attempt at installing sass may have caused this. I followed [these instructions](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3), thus doing these commands earlier in the day.

```
$ export GEM_HOME=/home/mygemrepository
$ ruby setup.rb --prefix=/home/mystuff
```

Again, I don't if that matters as GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH seem correct.

```
$ echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
$ echo $GEM_PATH
/Users/sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/sjc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're missing openssl.  Checkout: https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

Comment: Thank you. This led in the right direction. I ended up having trouble downloading openssl directly. So I redownloaded Homebrew, then reinstalled all the packages (including openssl, via `brew install openssl`) as explained here: http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion
Now I'm up and running beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Examples for ruby 2.3.1, or may be other version of ruby.

Without reinstall rvm:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Or with reinstall rvm:

```
rvm implode
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Or with custom rubygems for ruby < 2.3:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.2.2 --rubygems 2.7.10 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

PS: after all may be reinstall all ruby versions

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is if your default version of Ruby is old.

Most OS come preinstalled with Ruby, but use an older versions of Ruby (1.8.x), rather than 2.x or even 1.9.x and that may cause the new version of rvm to fail.

$ rvm list
to see the list of ruby versions install, and use ("ruby use uby-1.9.3-p429" equivalent ) to set that and then try :
$ rvm get stable
(get the most recent bugfixes and ruby version updates )
$ rvm rubygems latest

I also changed the default ruby : 
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2

worked for me!